# PIPX install path change

Tags: python, pipx

I have Python installed in `c:\users\dan\appdata\roaming\python\python38\python.exe`. `pip install` is working correctly and I can run Python programs in my IDE. My problem is when I try to install something with `pipx` I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\dan>pipx install eth-brownie
No Python at 'c:\users\dan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe'
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    C:\Users\dan\.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2021-11-22_01.21.33_pip_errors.log

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

I understand `pipx` seeks `python.exe` in a wrong directory, but I don't know why because Python were installed to a different location and paths are fine (`PYTHONPATH = C:\Users\dan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38`). My question is that how can make `pipx` to search `python.exe` in `\appdata\roaming\python\python38\` instead of `appdata\local\programs\python\python38\`?

(`cmd_2021-11-22_01.21.33_pip_errors.log` is not existing in the folder where the error messages points, therefore I couldn't see that log)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uninstall `pipx` with `pip uninstall pipx`. Then remove the `$home/.local/pipx` directory completely. Use `get-command pipx` in a PowerShell prompt to find out if there are older (and corrupt) copies of `pipx` installed somewhere. Remove them also. Then reinstall `pipx`.

For Windows: the local pipx dir can be in `$home/AppData/Local/pipx`.

Comment: After being stuck with pipx trying to use python in the windowsapp folder for ages, this was the fix I needed! Thank you!!!

Comment: Deleting the local pipx made my solution. I found it in another win path, so I edited your answer to add that alternative path. Thanks!