# pipx install eth-brownie error : Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:

Tags: python, brownie, pipx

Hi I am trying to install Brownie but I seem to run into the below issue.

```
C:\Users\gmlad>pipx install eth-brownie

Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    C:\Users\gmlad\.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2021-12-03_16.35.47_pip_errors.log

pip failed to build packages:
    bitarray
    cytoolz
    lru-dict
    multidict
    psutil
    yarl

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace?

Comment: I think so, its what I get when I run (pipx install eth-brownie) in my cmd

Comment: Does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679343/pipx-failed-to-build-packages or this: help? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/112042/link1120-error-when-attempting-to-install-brownie-with-pipx-install-eth-brownie

Comment: Hi Patrick, I am following along on your tutorial, so thanks for the content. Regarding the first link I was initially getting different errors so I installed the windows c++ build tools. After which I got the error above. I also try install cytoolz and cython etc . via pip and pipx and get different errors. I have also tried reverting to older versions of python but still didnt seem to work

Comment: Hi @PatrickCollins any suggestions ?

Comment: I'd recommend trying WSL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install and installing everything with that.

Comment: @PatrickCollins thanks so much will give it a bash! apologies for being such a pain :D

Answer (score 1):

This is not the `eth-brownie` problem, but overall `pipx` issue.
I've got the same error after switching from Python 3.9 to 3.10 on Arch Linux.
This answer solved it, although it's for Windows) Try it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70080178/13389142