# Unable to install brownie using pipx

Tags: python, pip, brownie, pipx

This is what i got after runing the command pipx install eth-brownie

```
C:\Windows\system32>pipx install eth-brownie
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. 

pip failed to build package:
    cytoolz

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\functoolz.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

On installing cytoolz using pip this is what I get :

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install cytoolz
Requirement already satisfied: cytoolz in c:\users\goosa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in c:\users\goosa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from cytoolz) (0.11.1)
```

I see there are other ways to install brownie but I don't understand how to create a virtual environment and do other things.
I don't know what else to do, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the github installation method and it worked for me, these are the commands that I used on VSCode terminal. The last line can be python3 or python based on your setup.

```
git clone https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie.git
cd brownie
python setup.py install
```

I already tried the other installation methods by installing pipx, pip, cython, cytoolz but none of them worked and was giving me different errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link for the correct installation

> https://chain.link/bootcamp/brownie-setup-instructions

Try installing Cython first with `pip install Cython` and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: I tried this but was getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem of `pipx` and it's still possible to install it this way. See my answer to another same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70397128/13389142