# Problems installing Brownie(1.17.2) on Windows 10 Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x

So I tried to install brownie(1.17.2) on windows 10 (python 3.9) and keep getting the same errors.

```
pip failed to build packages:
    bitarray
    cytoolz
    lru-dict

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

**What I have tried**
reinstalling python
downloading the binaries manually
download form the git repo directly

when downloading and installing from the git repo it cant install bitarray (1.2.2):

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\dante\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dante\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wx9cxs0x\\bitarray_c385a97c876d4948a1f2f2438f0745d6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dante\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wx9cxs0x\\bitarray_c385a97c876d4948a1f2f2438f0745d6\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dante\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ht3hodgy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\dante\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\bitarray' Check the logs for full command output.
```

after installing and running pip check it says that a lot of stuf is not installled:

```
web3 5.25.0 requires aiohttp, which is not installed.
web3 5.25.0 requires pywin32, which is not installed.
vyper 0.3.1 requires asttokens, which is not installed.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 requires aiohttp, which is not installed.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 requires aiosignal, which is not installed.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 requires asttokens, which is not installed.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 requires async-timeout, which is not installed.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 requires asynctest, which is not installed.
eth-account 0.5.6 has requirement bitarray<1.3.0,>=1.2.1, but you have bitarray 2.3.5.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 has requirement bitarray==1.2.2, but you have bitarray 2.3.5.
```

Comment: I do see 5 different versions of Python here (https://www.python.org/downloads/). you could, at least, tell which version of Python you are using?   (the same is obviously true for the version of Brownie you are trying to install)

Comment: Sorry forgot, I have added it now

Comment: Have you tried the `-v` option for pip to get more information? [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/)

Comment: [Unable to install brownie using pipx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70315764/unable-to-install-brownie-using-pipx) has an answer that seems to work.

Comment: adding (the neede version of) `bitarray` should be possible using `pip install "bitarray>=1.2.2,<=1.2.2"`.

Comment: It was a problem with the c++ build tools. I fixed it by reinstalling windows. I think I messed up my windows while working on trying to fix this. I don't call this a good solution but it works now I guess.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70315764/unable-to-install-brownie-using-pipx) answer (from less than a month ago) seems to work:

```
git clone https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie.git
cd brownie
python setup.py install
```

After installing the output from `pip check` gives:

```
D:\TEMP>pip check
eth-brownie 1.17.2 has requirement charset-normalizer==2.0.9, but you have charset-normalizer 2.0.8.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 has requirement cytoolz==0.11.2, but you have cytoolz 0.11.0.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 has requirement pygments==2.10.0, but you have pygments 2.11.2.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 has requirement python-dateutil==2.8.1, but you have python-dateutil 2.8.2.
eth-brownie 1.17.2 has requirement pyyaml==5.4.1, but you have pyyaml 6.0.
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work tis is what is the error that i get https://pastebin.com/2ej6VUGN

Comment: The log stops when trying to install `lru-dict`. you could try to install that manually by doing: `pip install "lru-dict<2.0.0,>=1.1.7"`, but that can be a long way before `eth-brownie` will be completely installed.